# Redux saga use Call effect with generic function type typescript

Tags: typescript, redux-saga

I'm currently using Redux-saga and typescript. But I don't know how to use `call` effect with `generic function type` in Typescript.

For eg. I have a function with generic type like this:

```
function identity<T>(arg: T): T {
    return arg;
}
```

And, in saga, I expect the code like this:

```
...
const result = yield call(identity<string>, "myString")
...
```

However the compiler shows errors. Of course, I can write

```
const result = yield call(identity, "myString")
```

But it's not my expectation. How can I know is there any way/syntax to satisfies my above expectation?

Comment: `const result = yield call(identity, "myString")` why doesn't this work for you? This is the way i'd do it, except i'd also give an explicit type to result, as in `const result: string = /*etc*/`

Comment: @NicholasTower In my example, I just return the same type with argument, so do as yours is good, but in some case, it return another type not T. The thing I want is make sure the function received explicitly defined type when used in `call` effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible solution is to define type of `identity` function and use it to specialize `call` invocation.

```
type identityFunction<T> = (agr: T) => T;
```

And provide type to `call` function

```
yield call<identityFunction<string>>(identity, 'myString');
```

Now, if you try to call `yield call<identityFunction<string>>` with wrong arguments (also if signature of identity function will not match type `identityFunction<T>`), TypeScript will display error.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [module augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation) to add an additional typing to the `"redux-saga/effects"` module that is similar to the `Function.apply` typing:

```
import { CallEffect } from 'redux-saga/effects';

declare module 'redux-saga/effects' {
  export function call<A extends any[], R>(fn: (...args: A) => R, ...args: A): CallEffect<R>;
}
```

Make sure this is in a typescript file (`*.ts`), not a declaration file (`*.d.ts`).

Not sure why this isn't the official typing.

Comment: best answer, but why declaring it in *.ts file work but not *.d.ts file?

Comment: That is a great question that I don't have an answer to. In TS's official module augmentation docs, they put it in a `.ts` file. I think because otherwise it overwrites the types for the entire module, not just what you changed/added, but I'm not sure. 

Lately I've been using vue3 and their type shims are similar to this but they can go in a `.d.ts` file

Answer (score 1):

You can try saga return type SagaIterator

```
import { SagaIterator } from '@redux-saga/core';
import { put, select, call } from 'redux-saga/effects';
function identity<T>(arg: T): SagaIterator  {
...
  yield call([identityFunction<string>>],identity, 'myString');
...
}
```